# Why does af(x) cause vertical dilation, while f(bx) causes horizontal dilation, when both of the increase/decrease the y value of any given x value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, transformation

Especially for something like a log or a quadratic graph, where increasing “b” has virtually the same effect as increasing “a”. Both give a higher y-value for any given x-value, which should be considered vertical stretching (as it increases the gradient). And yet, when b is increased, f(bx) is considered as horizontal compression. Why is this?

Comment: Put one way, $af(x)$ acts on $f(x)$, the output of the function $f$, while $f(bx)$ acts on the input to the function $f$. Therefore, the placements of the constants $a$ and $b$ ensure that one acts on the output of $f$, and the other changes the input of $f$. So $f(x) \to af(x)$ is a change on the $y$ axis, while $x \to bx$ is a change to the $x$ axis.

Comment: Apply your reasoning to $f(x) = \sin x$ and see what happens.  There's no vertical stretching in $\sin(4x).$